# Run Android Studio Libgdx Game on Emulator Without Building HTML

Tags: android, android-studio, libgdx

When I try to run my libgdx game using the AndroidLauncher in Android Studio, I keep getting an error because one of the dependencies I'm using (FreeTypeFontGenerator) is not compatible with HTML.

```
:html:addSource
:html:compileGwt
Compiling module io.github.mygame.GdxDefinition
   Tracing compile failure path for type 
  'io.github.mygame.resources.HighScore'
      [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/C:/Users/mygame/core/src/io/github/mygame//resources/HighScore.java'
     [ERROR] Line 14: No source code is available for type com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.freetype.FreeTypeFontGenerator; did you forget to inherit a required module?
```

Is it possible to build/run the game on the Android Studio emulator without building/compiling the HTML code at all?  Or do I simply need to entirely remove the HTML Libgdx code from my game if I won't be using HTML?  I just want to test out my game on my Android device. 
The DesktopLauncher is working just fine and giving me no errors.

Answer (score 0):

It does not compile the html module when deploying on Android, so there's a problem in your run configuration.